# Getting the first string from a tuple which is a key of a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, key

I have a following python dictionary:

```
lines = {('mid', 'north'): None,
         ('south', 'mid'): None,
         ('south', 'north'): None,
        }
```

what I am trying to achieve is to get the first string or/and second string of one of the keys of the `lines` dictionary.

so `lines.keys()` gives me `dict_keys([('mid', 'north'), ('south', 'mid'), ('south', 'north')])`

what I would like to have is something like this:

```
lines.keys()[0][0]
'mid'
```

ofc it is not working like this but is there a function or a command which gives me the first string of the tuple `('mid', 'north')`, as an output? Keep in mind `('mid', 'north')` is the key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `dict_keys` to tuple, since it is iterable:

```
>>> k = tuple(lines.keys())
>>> k[0][0]
'mid'
```

Comment: This looks like the easiest solution ty. And it works. Btw when you do `k = list(lines.keys())` and then `k[0][0]` gives `mid` and not `'mid'`, can u explain why is that? and also add to your answer?

Comment: `k[0][0]` contains the string `mid`. In python you would write that as `'mid'` (or `"mid"`), but if you do `print(k[0][0])` it would just output string's content (`mid`). If you want to obtain the string *representation*, do `print(repr(k[0][0]))`, and it will print `'mid'`. The interactive console gives you the string representation by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your keys to list, and since dict will be in random order you need to [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) it.

```
lines = {('mid', 'north'): None,
         ('south', 'mid'): None,
         ('south', 'north'): None,
        }

print(list(sorted(lines.keys()))[0][0]) # -> mid
```

Comment: Looks nice, but why sorted?

Comment: I don't think it will be in random order, but it will be the order I set them. so `[0]` is always `('mid', 'north')`, and `[1]` is `('south', 'mid')`, etc...

Comment: No it won't try `print(lines.keys())` running that  couple of times.